# C# : Label is not showing data

Tags: c#, sql, label

```
{
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=jayi-pc\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DB_test1;Integrated Security=True");
        con2.Open();
        SqlCommand sc3 = new SqlCommand(@"Select * from Visitor_1");
        sc3.Connection = con2;
        SqlDataReader dr3 = sc3.ExecuteReader();

        dr3.Read();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
        frm2.label1.Text = dr3["Id"].ToString();
        frm2.label2.Text = dr3["Name"].ToString();
        frm2.label3.Text = dr3["Address"].ToString();
        frm2.label4.Text = dr3["Purpose"].ToString();
        frm2.label5.Text = dr3["Phone No"].ToString();
        dr3.Close();
        con2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Not sure what's the problem/question is, but settings the labels *after* displaying a dialog form hardly seems right. You probably want to set them before calling `ShowDialog`

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint? Please read [ask], you should try to use the description section of your question to *describe* your problem, and what steps you have taken to try to solve it

Comment: Juergen my question is in form2(frm2) I can't see the data

Comment: Oh well, let's make it a full answer then

Answer (score 2):

Your code would work if you were displaying the form with `Show`. However, `ShowDialog` is synchronous, therefore your label assignment isn't executed until the form is closed. Just move that bit of code before the call to `ShowDialog`.

```
this.Hide();
frm2.label1.Text = dr3["Id"].ToString();
frm2.label2.Text = dr3["Name"].ToString();
frm2.label3.Text = dr3["Address"].ToString();
frm2.label4.Text = dr3["Purpose"].ToString();
frm2.label5.Text = dr3["Phone No"].ToString();
frm2.ShowDialog();
```